# Unable to finish Lost of the Ages

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim, skyrim-dawnguard

While following a quest, I ended in **Mzulft** where I found the Dwarven Storageroom. Playing as a garbage collector, I cleaned it all, including the Glowing Crystal Shard.

Several hours later, after complete the Dawnguard Questline by killing Lord Harkon, I decided to do the sidequests and then I read the book *The Aetherium Wars*, however the misc quest **Investigate the ruins of Arkngthamz** did not trigger.

I searched about and I have seen people with the same problem but they completed, in the way of forge one of the Aetherium equipments, by traveling by their own.

I did the same, but Katria's Ghost was not present in any of the locations a Crystal Shard could be taken and, now in **Ruins of Bthalft**, without her ghost again, I can't activate the **Dwarven Mechanism** to access the Aetherium Forge.

More search for possible solutions involving `setstage` and `setquest` console commands, I tried then all, with several different quest stages and nothing happen.

Will I stay with this Steam achievement uncompleted?

Comment: If all you're worried about is the achievement, you can use Steam Achievement Manager to give it to yourself; alternatively there are mods that give you achievements for free, though I'm not sure any of them are granular enough to give you just that achievement.

Comment: Is the quest showing up in your quest log as finished or not? If it is, then I would turn to the Achievement Manager (which was made specifically for instances like this). If not, then give me a little time to look it over.

Comment: **kotekzot**: I didn't know about this possibility. It's not very good but, if there is no other solution... Besides I'm interested in Achievements, the Aetherial Crown is a very good adding, specially now I'm planning to enable a mod to make things harder than Legendary mode.

**Unionhawk**: The quest even started. When I read the book I was expecting a misc quest become available, but maybe because I already had one Glowing Shard -OR- because I had finish the DG questline, it didn't appear.

Answer (score 2):

1 of the 4 Shards is called "Glowing crystal shard" and can be dropped into containers, so its probably in your house or in a vendors inventory.

You can only activate the forge with 4 pieces, so you will have to hunt down the last piece in your house/vendors.